# How about the inclusion relation between $H^1$ and $C^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

If $u$ satisfies a Poisson's equation in a compact support domain $U$
$$
- \nabla \cdot ( \nabla u) = f
$$
then $u$ must be a $C^2$ function? Otherwise $\Delta u$ may be not well-defined.

The weak form of the Poisson's reads for any test function $v \in H^1(U)$ such that
$$
\int_U \nabla u \nabla v ~dx = \int_U f v ~dx
$$
This, on the other hand, requires $u$ an $H^1$ function?

The $u$ satisfies the Poisson's must also satisfies its weak form, but the converse is not true.

Claim:  $C^2 \subset H^1$ but $H^1 \not\subset C^2$.

1. Is this claim true? For the compact support domain $U$? For any open bounded domain $V$? For $\mathbb{R}^n$?
2. Can this be extended such as $C^{k+1} \subset H^k$ but $H^k \not\subset C^{k+1}$? This result conflicts with the Sobolev embedding theorem?

Answer (score 2):

I will use Evans' definitions of the $C^k$ spaces, that is

**Definition.**
Let $\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}n,m,k\in\mathbb N$ or $k=\infty$, let $U\subset\mathbb R^n$ be an open set and let $V\subset\mathbb R^m$ or $V\subset\mathbb C^m$. We will use the notations ($V$ may be omitted; also, "$0$-times continuously differentiable" means "continuous")
\begin{align*}
 C^k(U;V):=\{u:U\to V:u\text{ is $k$-times continuously differentiable}\}, \\
 C^k(\bar U;V):=\{u:U\to V:D^{\mathbf k} u\text{ is uniformly continuous on all bounded subsets of $U$,} \\\text{for all $\mathbf k\in\mathbb N_0^n$ with $\lvert\mathbf k\rvert\le k$}\}.
 \end{align*}

---

Then we see: If $U$ is bounded, then $C^k(U)\subset H^k(U)$ is false (because $C^k(U)\subset L^2(U)$ is false) but $C^k(\bar U)\subset H^k(\bar U)$ is true. In particular, we have $$C^{k+1}(\bar U)\subset C^k(\bar U)\subset H^k(\bar U).$$

Also, for $U$ non-empty, $H^k(\bar U)\subset C^k(\bar U)$ is false. But Sobolev embedding (Winfried Kaballo. *Aufbaukurs Funktionalanalysis und Operatortheorie.* Springer Spektrum, 2013, Theorem 4.11) does give $$H^{k+1}(\mathbb R)\subset C^{k}(\bar{\mathbb R})$$ and there are analogous results for other domains than $\mathbb R$. There are two abuses of notation here:

1. $\subset$ actually means "can be embedded by changing each function only on a set of Lebesgue measure zero"
2. $\bar{\mathbb R}$ means "the $C^{k}$-norm is finite".

---

*Exercise.* Prove that we always have (under the right conditions, but I am tired now) $$C^{k+1}(\bar U)\subset W^{k+1,\infty}(\bar U)\subset W^{k+1,\infty}(\bar U).$$

Comment: $C^k(U)$ may not be inside $H^k$ but each ball in $C^k$ is, which is not too bad.

Comment: Also there is a small caveat which is that I am not quite sure what happens if $U$ doesn't have a $C^k$ boundary, but then again it is almost 3am here so I won't check

Comment: Re: smoothness of the boundary, if the boundary is smooth enough (e.g. Lipschitz) then neighbourhoods around boundary points look like polygons which have the same scaling as any other point. When the boundary is spiky it is 'easier' to be integrable near the boundary, i.e. 'harder' to be bounded and hence the Sobolev embedding $H^{s} \subset C^k$ in dimension $d$, which in the Lipschitz case is $s>k+d/2$, needs a larger $s$ to compensate. (This is somewhere in Adams and Fournier.) And a perhaps obvious remark for the OP, $H^k(U) = H^k(\overline U)$

Comment: @Calvin Thank you! And yes, obviously $H^k(U)=H^k(\bar U)$ (my choice of notation only serves to highlight that the norm is finite, but of course $H^k(U)$ is always a space of functions with finite $H^k$-norm ).